# Loop plot using user defined data input

Tags: plotting, data, procedural-programming

I am trying to run this code using a single loop.  Values for variables $a$ and $b$ are user defined (not random data).  Below is my code,

```
ClearAll;
f[a_, b_] := a*x^2 + b*x + 12 - a - b;

a1 = 1; b1 = 2;
plot1 = Plot[f[a1, b1], {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed[
  "Curve Plot\n" <> " a=" <> ToString[a1] <> " b=" <> 
   ToString[b1] ] ]];

a2 = 2; b2 = 2;
plot2 = Plot[f[a1, b1], {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed[
  "Curve Plot\n" <> " a=" <> ToString[a2] <> " b=" <> 
   ToString[b2] ] ]];

a3 = 1; b3 = 3;
plot3 = Plot[f[a1, b1], {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed[
  "Curve Plot\n" <> " a=" <> ToString[a3] <> " b=" <> 
   ToString[b3] ] ]];

a4 = 1; b4 = 4;
plot4 = Plot[f[a1, b1], {x, 0, 10}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[Framed[
  "Curve Plot\n" <> " a=" <> ToString[a4] <> " b=" <> 
   ToString[b4] ] ]];
plottotal = 
Column[{GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}, {plot3, plot4}}, 
PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Data Plots"], 18, Black, Bold], 
ImageSize -> 1180]}]
```

Data $a$ and $b$ can be in matrix, grid or table format. How to run a loop from set of input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to put your input in a matrix and then map over it

```
ClearAll;
f[a_,b_]:=a*x^2+b*x+12-a-b;
input={{1,2},{2,2},{1,3},{1,4}};

plots={a=#[[1]];b=#[[2]];Plot[f[a,b],{x,0,10},
     PlotLabel->Style[Framed["Curve Plot\n"<>" a="<>
     ToString[a]<>" b="<>ToString[b]]]]}&/@input;

GraphicsGrid[Partition[Flatten@plots,2],
    PlotLabel->Style[Framed["Data Plots"],18,Black,Bold],ImageSize->500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (`@@@`). First, I've redefined your function just because it bothers me to not have `x` as an argument:

```
f[x_, a_, b_] := a*x^2 + b*x + 12 - a - b;
```

Set up your list of `{a, b}` parameters:

```
paramlist = {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
```

Then you can make your `Plot` a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and `Apply` it to each element in `paramlist`:

```
plots = Plot[f[x, #1, #2], {x, 0, 10}, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[Framed[
       "Curve Plot\n" <> " a=" <> ToString[#1] <> " b=" <> ToString[#2]]]
    ] & @@@ paramlist;
```

This gives you back a list of your plots, which you can then [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) into two columns (however many plots there are in the list) and put it into a `GraphicsGrid`. (I don't think the `Column` part was really necessary.)

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[plots, 2, 2, {1}, {}], 
 PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Data Plots"], 18, Black, Bold], 
 ImageSize -> 750]
```

[image]

The extra arguments in `Partition[plots, 2, 2, {1}, {}]` are just so that it all still works if there are an odd number of plots, and the last one doesn't get cut off.